Я хочу написать функцию, которая принимала бы на вход курсор и возвращала часть курсора. PostgreSQL
Пытаюсь написать универсальную функцию, которая принимает на вход pi_cursor refcursor, pi_start int, pi_end int.
Как сделать так, чтобы функция вернула строки из курсора, которые по порядку находятся между pi_start и pi_end?

Эммм... а в каком формате вы хотите получить на выходе эти строки? в виде нового курсора, временной таблицы, табличной переменной, массива, что-то ещё?

Хотел бы получить на выходе курсор, но не понимаю как из одного курсора передать отфильтрованные данные во второй.

По-моему, это невозможно... тут либо открывать новый курсор, докинув на текст старого требуемые ограничения, либо вместо функции, возвращающей новый курсор, делать универсальный фетчер. Хотя всё равно не понимаю, зачем нужна такая дополнительная прослойка.

А как возможно тогда это реализовать, если возвращать не курсор, а в каком-либо другом виде
